# Getting Misplaced alignment tab character & Error in an array

Tags: latex

I'm working on writing a paper on Latex and I'm getting Misplaced alignment tab character & error in an equation. I couldn't resovle the problem. Can you tell me what's wrong with the table?

```
\begin{equation}  
wscore(w_i)= \left\{  
begin{array}{l l}  
  1 & \text{if} \, (w_i \in DKW) \land (w_i \not\in FW)\\  
  0 & \text{if} \, (w_i \not\in DKW) \lor (w_i \in FW)\\  
\end{array}  
\right.  
\end{equation}
```

I get Misplaced alignment tab character & error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `\` missing before `begin{array}`

Unrelated to the problem, but better not write whole words like `wscore` in math italic, the kerning will be completely messed up

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation}  
\mathrm{wscore}(w_i)= \left\{  
\begin{array}{ll}  
  1 & \text{if} \, (w_i \in DKW) \land (w_i \not\in FW)\\  
  0 & \text{if} \, (w_i \not\in DKW) \lor (w_i \in FW)\\  
\end{array}  
\right.  
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the problem. But now I'm having a new error: Undifined control sequence: 1 & \text{if} \, (w_i \in DKW) \land (w_i \not\in FW)\\
Help please.

Comment: @ihebmeddeb Does the document in my answer work for you?

Comment: @ihebmeddeb Maybe you are interested in https://texnique.fr/osqa/ - a dedicated questions and answer site for latex

Comment: Well, I don't get the character & error anymore but I'm having another error now!!

Comment: @ihebmeddeb Does the document from my answer also produce an error?

Comment: No, it's working fine. Just had a problem with \text{if}. Fixed it by adding mathtools package.